# How do I fix my 4 row by 4 column array so it looks nice?

Tags: html, css

I want a table type page that I can print off on a single 8 by 11 page with the following criteria:

I want a math expression at the top centered with 0 margin from the top of each box(inside).
*Also I want a circled number in the very center of each box.
I want a math expression at the left centered written vertically with a margin of 0 from the left of each inside box.
I want a math expression at the right centered written vertically with a margin of 0 from the right of each inside box.
I want a math expression at the bottom centered with 0 margin from the bottom of each box(inside).

I have played with numbers. Commented out or in a few properties. I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong or what is actually happening sometimes.

I'm new to html and css so I'm sorry if this is a dumb question.
Also, thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Factoring Puzzle-sum of cubes/ differences of cubes/ quadratics/ gcf!</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<!--first row-->
<div class="row">
<!--first column-->
<div class="column">
    <!--first square-->
    <div class="square">
      
    <div class="topsidesquare">
    
    <p>6x<sup>2</sup>-8</p>
    </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
        9</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
    <div class="leftsidesquare">
    <p>6x-16</p>
    </div>
    <div class="rightsidesquare">
       <p> 5x<sup>3</sup>-125x</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomsidesquare">
    <p>x<sup>5</sup>-64x<sup>2</sup></p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--second column-->
<div class="column">
     <!--second square-->
    <div class="square">
           <div class="topsidesquare">
            <p>5x<sup>2</sup>-23x-8</p>
            </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
        6</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
            <div class="leftsidesquare">
            <p>5x(x-5)(x+5)</p>
            </div>
    <div class="rightsidesquare">
    <p>6x<sup>2</sup>-46x-16</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomsidesquare">
    <p>x<sup>3</sup> +64  </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--third column-->
<div class="column">
     <!--third square-->
    <div class="square">
           <div class="topsidesquare">
               <p>3x<sup>2</sup>-23x-2</p>

            </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
        16</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      
            <div class="leftsidesquare">
            <p>2(3x+1)(x-8)</p>
            </div>
    <div class="rightsidesquare">
    <p>(2x-1)(4x<sup>2</sup>+2x+1)</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomsidesquare">
    <p>-2x<sup>4</sup>-128x </p>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--fourth column-->
<div class="column">
    <!--fourth square-->
    <div class="square">
           <div class="topsidesquare">
               <p>3x<sup>2</sup>+23x-8</p>

            </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
        2</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
            <div class="leftsidesquare">
            <p>8x<sup>3</sup>-1</p>
            </div>
    <div class="rightsidesquare">
    <p>27x<sup>2</sup>-3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomsidesquare">
    <p>2x<sup>3</sup>+5x<sup>2</sup>+6x+15</p>
    </div>
    </div> 
</div>

</div>

<!--STARTING MY 2nd ROW HERE (FINGERS CROSSED!)-->
    <div class="row">
    <!--first column-->
    <div class="column">
        <!--first square-->
        <div class="square">
        <div class="topsidesquare">
            <p>x<sup>2</sup>(x-4)(x<sup>2</sup>+4x+16)</p>

        </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            15</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
        <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>(x-4)(x-4)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
           <p> 27x<sup>3</sup>-125</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>(3x+1)(x-8)</p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--second column-->
    <div class="column">
         <!--second square-->
        <div class="square">
               <div class="topsidesquare">
                   <p>(x+4)(x<sup>2</sup>-4x+16)</p>

                </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            5</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
                <div class="leftsidesquare">
                <p>(3x-5)(9x<sup>2</sup>+15x+25)</p>
                </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>4</sup>-6x<sup>3</sup>+8x<sup>2</sup></p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>4</sup> +343x</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--third column-->
    <div class="column">
         <!--third square-->
        <div class="square">
               <div class="topsidesquare">
                   <p>-2x(x+4)(x<sup>2</sup>-4x+16)</p>

                </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            1</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
                <div class="leftsidesquare">
                <p>x<sup>2</sup>(x-2)(x-4)</p>
                </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>-1000</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>-2x<sup>5</sup>-128x<sup>2</sup> </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--fourth column-->
    <div class="column">
        <!--fourth square-->
        <div class="square">
               <div class="topsidesquare">
                   <p>(2x+5)(x<sup>2</sup>+3)</p>

                </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            8</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
                <div class="leftsidesquare">
                <p>(x-10)(x<sup>2</sup>+10x+100)</p>
                </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>-4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>2x<sup>3</sup>-50x</p>
        </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

    </div>
<!--STARTING MY THIRD ROW HERE!!!-->
    <div class="row">
    <!--first column-->
    <div class="column">
        <!--first square-->
        <div class="square">
        <div class="topsidesquare">
            <p>3x<sup>2</sup>-23x-8</p>

        </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            14</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
        <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>2</sup>+16</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
           <p> 6x<sup>2</sup>+11x+4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>2x<sup>2</sup>y-7xy-9y</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--second column-->
    <div class="column">
         <!--second square-->
        <div class="square">
               <div class="topsidesquare">
                   <p>x(x+7)(x<sup>2</sup>-7x+49)</p>

                </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            3</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
                <div class="leftsidesquare">
                <p>(2x+1)(3x+4)</p>
                </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p> 4x<sup>3</sup>+2x<sup>2</sup>-20x</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>125x<sup>3</sup> -1000  </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--third column-->
    <div class="column">
         <!--third square-->
        <div class="square">
               <div class="topsidesquare">
                   <p>-2x<sup>2</sup>(x+4)(x<sup>2</sup>-4x+16)</p>

                </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            7</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
                <div class="leftsidesquare">
                <p>2x(x-2)(2x+5)</p>
                </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>15x<sup>3</sup>+3x</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>8x<sup>2</sup>y+34xy+21y </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--fourth column-->
    <div class="column">
        <!--fourth square-->
        <div class="square">
               <div class="topsidesquare">
                   <p>2x(x-5)(x+5)</p>

                </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            11</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
                <div class="leftsidesquare">
                <p>3x(5x<sup>2</sup>+1)</p>
                </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>-16</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>2x<sup>3</sup>+15x<sup>2</sup>-2x-15</p>
        </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

    </div>
<!--MY LAST AND FINAL ROW-->
    <div class="row">
    <!--first column-->
    <div class="column">
        <!--first square-->
        <div class="square">
        <div class="topsidesquare">
            <p>y(x+1)(2x-9)</p>

        </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            4</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
        <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>2</sup>-9</p>
        </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
           <p> y<sup>2</sup>-25</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>2</sup>-81</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--second column-->
    <div class="column">
         <!--second square-->
        <div class="square">
               <div class="topsidesquare">
                   <p>125(x-2)(x<sup>2</sup>+2x+4)</p>
                </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            12</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
                <div class="leftsidesquare">
                <p>(y-5)(y+5)</p>
                </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p> x<sup>3</sup>-8x<sup>2</sup>-x-8</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup> +81  </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--third column-->
    <div class="column">
         <!--third square-->
        <div class="square">
               <div class="topsidesquare">
                   <p>y(4x+3)(2x+7)</p>

                </div>
          <!--   -->
          <div class="center">
            <div class="circleNumber">
            10</div>
          </div>
          <!--   -->
                <div class="leftsidesquare">
                <p>(x-1)(x+1)(x+8)</p>
                </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>4xy+y+4x+1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>+343 </p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--fourth column-->
    <div class="column">
        <!--fourth square-->
        <div class="square">
               <div class="topsidesquare">
                   <p>(2x+15)(x-1)(x+1)</p>
                 <!--   -->
                 <div class="center">
                   <div class="circleNumber">
                   13</div>
                 </div>
                 <!--   -->
                </div>
                <div class="leftsidesquare">
                <p>(y+1)(4x+1)</p>
                </div>
        <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>-343</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>2x<sup>3</sup>+5x<sup>2</sup>+18x+45</p>
        </div>
        </div> 
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS Code:

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    display:block;
    font-size: 14px;
    height:8in;
    width:8in;
}

.column{
    float:left;
    
    width:25%;
    height: 400%;
    margin-left:0;
    margin-right:0;
    border: 0.001px solid black;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
   
}


.row{
  height:10%;
}



.square{
  display:inline-block;
  position:absolute;
}


.square .bottomsidesquare {
    text-align:center;
    
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 10px;
  
    position: relative;
}



 .square .topsidesquare{
   
    text-align:center;
     left: 10px;
     position: relative;
}

.square .rightsidesquare{
  right: 2%;
  left:98%;
  top:30%;
  bottom: 150%;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed ; 
  position: relative;
}


 .square .leftsidesquare{
    
    /*float:left;
    padding-left:0px;
    padding-right:95%;
    padding-top:50%;
    padding-bottom:50%;*/
    left: 2%;
    right: 98%;
    top: 40%;
    bottom:40%;
     
    writing-mode: vertical-rl;
    text-orientation: mixed;
    position: relative;
 
}



 .square .center{
  display:inline-block ; 
  top: 40%;
  bottom:40%;
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  
}

.center{
  
  position:relative;
  top:160%;
  left:100%;
}
.circleNumber{
  border-radius:90%;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  padding:1px;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align:center;
  position:relative;
}
```

Played with properties and numbers that correspond to properties with different units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're trying too hard by using hard coded % values.
May I suggest css grid ?

Please refer to this for an in-depth guide:  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 8in;
  width: 8in;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.row {
  height: 25%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.square {
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "top top top" 
  "left center right" 
  "bottom bottom bottom";
  text-align: center;
}

.topsidesquare {
  grid-area: top;
}

.bottomsidesquare {
  grid-area: bottom;
  align-self: end;
}

.rightsidesquare {
  grid-area: right;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
}

.leftsidesquare {
  grid-area: left;
  writing-mode: vertical-rl;
  text-orientation: mixed;
  justify-self: start;
}

.center {
  grid-area: center;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}

.circleNumber {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 3ch;
  height: 3ch;
  padding: 1px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<!--first row-->
<div class="row">
  <!--first column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--first square-->
    <div class="square">

      <div class="topsidesquare">

        <p>6x<sup>2</sup>-8</p>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          9</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>6x-16</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p> 5x<sup>3</sup>-125x</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>5</sup>-64x<sup>2</sup></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--second column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--second square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>5x<sup>2</sup>-23x-8</p>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          6</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>5x(x-5)(x+5)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>6x<sup>2</sup>-46x-16</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup> +64 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--third column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--third square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>3x<sup>2</sup>-23x-2</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          16</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->

      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>2(3x+1)(x-8)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>(2x-1)(4x<sup>2</sup>+2x+1)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>-2x<sup>4</sup>-128x </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--fourth column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--fourth square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>3x<sup>2</sup>+23x-8</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          2</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>8x<sup>3</sup>-1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>27x<sup>2</sup>-3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>2x<sup>3</sup>+5x<sup>2</sup>+6x+15</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<!--STARTING MY 2nd ROW HERE (FINGERS CROSSED!)-->
<div class="row">
  <!--first column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--first square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>2</sup>(x-4)(x<sup>2</sup>+4x+16)</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          15</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>(x-4)(x-4)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p> 27x<sup>3</sup>-125</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>(3x+1)(x-8)</p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--second column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--second square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>(x+4)(x<sup>2</sup>-4x+16)</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          5</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>(3x-5)(9x<sup>2</sup>+15x+25)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>4</sup>-6x<sup>3</sup>+8x<sup>2</sup></p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>4</sup> +343x</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--third column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--third square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>-2x(x+4)(x<sup>2</sup>-4x+16)</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          1</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>2</sup>(x-2)(x-4)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>-1000</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>-2x<sup>5</sup>-128x<sup>2</sup> </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--fourth column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--fourth square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>(2x+5)(x<sup>2</sup>+3)</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          8</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>(x-10)(x<sup>2</sup>+10x+100)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>-4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>2x<sup>3</sup>-50x</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!--STARTING MY THIRD ROW HERE!!!-->
<div class="row">
  <!--first column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--first square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>3x<sup>2</sup>-23x-8</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          14</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>2</sup>+16</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p> 6x<sup>2</sup>+11x+4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>2x<sup>2</sup>y-7xy-9y</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--second column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--second square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>x(x+7)(x<sup>2</sup>-7x+49)</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          3</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>(2x+1)(3x+4)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p> 4x<sup>3</sup>+2x<sup>2</sup>-20x</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>125x<sup>3</sup> -1000 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--third column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--third square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>-2x<sup>2</sup>(x+4)(x<sup>2</sup>-4x+16)</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          7</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>2x(x-2)(2x+5)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>15x<sup>3</sup>+3x</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>8x<sup>2</sup>y+34xy+21y </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--fourth column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--fourth square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>2x(x-5)(x+5)</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          11</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>3x(5x<sup>2</sup>+1)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>-16</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>2x<sup>3</sup>+15x<sup>2</sup>-2x-15</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!--MY LAST AND FINAL ROW-->
<div class="row">
  <!--first column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--first square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>y(x+1)(2x-9)</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          4</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>2</sup>-9</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p> y<sup>2</sup>-25</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>2</sup>-81</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--second column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--second square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>125(x-2)(x<sup>2</sup>+2x+4)</p>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          12</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>(y-5)(y+5)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p> x<sup>3</sup>-8x<sup>2</sup>-x-8</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup> +81 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--third column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--third square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>y(4x+3)(2x+7)</p>

      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="center">
        <div class="circleNumber">
          10</div>
      </div>
      <!--   -->
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>(x-1)(x+1)(x+8)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>4xy+y+4x+1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>+343 </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--fourth column-->
  <div class="column">
    <!--fourth square-->
    <div class="square">
      <div class="topsidesquare">
        <p>(2x+15)(x-1)(x+1)</p>
        <!--   -->
        <div class="center">
          <div class="circleNumber">
            13</div>
        </div>
        <!--   -->
      </div>
      <div class="leftsidesquare">
        <p>(y+1)(4x+1)</p>
      </div>
      <div class="rightsidesquare">
        <p>x<sup>3</sup>-343</p>
      </div>
      <div class="bottomsidesquare">
        <p>2x<sup>3</sup>+5x<sup>2</sup>+18x+45</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was also able to find a mislocated closing divide tag because of this answer. Thanks so much.